# remote server color doesn't look correct

Tags: emacs, remote-server, color-scheme

I use ssh to login remote server quite often and on the server I'll use tools like emacs, git, tmux, etc. I noticed that the color on the remote server is very ugly compared with local machine. Especially for emacs, I want to use solarize theme but on the remote server it doesn't really show the correct color.

Does anyone know how to improve the color on remote server?

I am using item2 and when running infocmp I got the following results:

```
#   Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /opt/sw/python/20201012/anaconda3/envs/i38/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors,
am, bce, ccc, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
colors#0x100, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#0x10000,
acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=\r,
csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=\n, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,
cvvis=\E[?12;25h, dch=\E[%p1%dP, dch1=\E[P, dim=\E[2m,
dl=\E[%p1%dM, dl1=\E[M, ech=\E[%p1%dX, ed=\E[J, el=\E[K,
el1=\E[1K, flash=\E[?5h$<100/>\E[?5l, home=\E[H,
hpa=\E[%i%p1%dG, ht=^I, hts=\EH, ich=\E[%p1%d@,
il=\E[%p1%dL, il1=\E[L, ind=\n, indn=\E[%p1%dS,
initc=\E]4;%p1%d;rgb\:%p2%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p3%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X/%p4%{255}%*%{1000}%/%2.2X\E\\,
invis=\E[8m, is2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, kDC=\E[3;2~,
kEND=\E[1;2F, kHOM=\E[1;2H, kIC=\E[2;2~, kLFT=\E[1;2D,
kNXT=\E[6;2~, kPRV=\E[5;2~, kRIT=\E[1;2C, ka1=\EOw,
ka3=\EOy, kb2=\EOu, kbs=^H, kc1=\EOq, kc3=\EOs, kcbt=\E[Z,
kcub1=\EOD, kcud1=\EOB, kcuf1=\EOC, kcuu1=\EOA,
kdch1=\E[3~, kend=\EOF, kent=\EOM, kf1=\EOP, kf10=\E[21~,
kf11=\E[23~, kf12=\E[24~, kf13=\E[1;2P, kf14=\E[1;2Q,
kf15=\E[1;2R, kf16=\E[1;2S, kf17=\E[15;2~, kf18=\E[17;2~,
kf19=\E[18;2~, kf2=\EOQ, kf20=\E[19;2~, kf21=\E[20;2~,
kf22=\E[21;2~, kf23=\E[23;2~, kf24=\E[24;2~,
kf25=\E[1;5P, kf26=\E[1;5Q, kf27=\E[1;5R, kf28=\E[1;5S,
kf29=\E[15;5~, kf3=\EOR, kf30=\E[17;5~, kf31=\E[18;5~,
kf32=\E[19;5~, kf33=\E[20;5~, kf34=\E[21;5~,
kf35=\E[23;5~, kf36=\E[24;5~, kf37=\E[1;6P, kf38=\E[1;6Q,
kf39=\E[1;6R, kf4=\EOS, kf40=\E[1;6S, kf41=\E[15;6~,
kf42=\E[17;6~, kf43=\E[18;6~, kf44=\E[19;6~,
kf45=\E[20;6~, kf46=\E[21;6~, kf47=\E[23;6~,
kf48=\E[24;6~, kf49=\E[1;3P, kf5=\E[15~, kf50=\E[1;3Q,
kf51=\E[1;3R, kf52=\E[1;3S, kf53=\E[15;3~, kf54=\E[17;3~,
kf55=\E[18;3~, kf56=\E[19;3~, kf57=\E[20;3~,
kf58=\E[21;3~, kf59=\E[23;3~, kf6=\E[17~, kf60=\E[24;3~,
kf61=\E[1;4P, kf62=\E[1;4Q, kf63=\E[1;4R, kf7=\E[18~,
kf8=\E[19~, kf9=\E[20~, khome=\EOH, kich1=\E[2~,
kind=\E[1;2B, kmous=\E[<, knp=\E[6~, kpp=\E[5~,
kri=\E[1;2A, mc0=\E[i, mc4=\E[4i, mc5=\E[5i, meml=\El,
memu=\Em, mgc=\E[?69l, oc=\E]104\007, op=\E[39;49m, rc=\E8,
rep=%p1%c\E[%p2%{1}%-%db, rev=\E[7m, ri=\EM,
rin=\E[%p1%dT, ritm=\E[23m, rmacs=\E(B, rmam=\E[?7l,
rmcup=\E[?1049l\E[23;0;0t, rmir=\E[4l, rmkx=\E[?1l\E>,
rmm=\E[?1034l, rmso=\E[27m, rmul=\E[24m,
rs1=\Ec\E]104\007, rs2=\E[!p\E[?3;4l\E[4l\E>, sc=\E7,
setab=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t4%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t10%p1%{8}%-%d%e48;5;%p1%d%;m,
setaf=\E[%?%p1%{8}%<%t3%p1%d%e%p1%{16}%<%t9%p1%{8}%-%d%e38;5;%p1%d%;m,
sgr=%?%p9%t\E(0%e\E(B%;\E[0%?%p6%t;1%;%?%p5%t;2%;%?%p2%t;4%;%?%p1%p3%|%t;7%;%?%p4%t;5%;%?%p7%t;8%;m,
sgr0=\E(B\E[m, sitm=\E[3m, smacs=\E(0, smam=\E[?7h,
smcup=\E[?1049h\E[22;0;0t,
smglr=\E[?69h\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%ds, smir=\E[4h,
smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smm=\E[?1034h, smso=\E[7m, smul=\E[4m,
tbc=\E[3g, u6=\E[%i%d;%dR, u7=\E[6n,
u8=\E[?%[;0123456789]c, u9=\E[c, vpa=\E[%i%p1%dd,
```

Comment: What terminal are you using and what is the output of `infocmp` when run on the remote host?

Comment: @petrucci4prez Thank you for the reply. I am using item2, and the codes are as follows:
    # Reconstructed via infocmp from file: /opt/sw/python/20201012/anaconda3/envs/i38/share/terminfo/x/xterm-256color
xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors,
 am, bce, ccc, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
 colors#0x100, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#0x10000,
 acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
 bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,

Comment: Please edit the additional information into your Question so that it can be formatted nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, and it's been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your terminal type is set to xterm-256color in Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Report Terminal Type.

https://iterm2.com/faq.html

> Q: How do I get 256 color mode working in vim?
>
> A: The recommended way is to set your terminal type to xterm-256color in Preferences > Profiles > Terminal > Report Terminal Type. You may also need to put set background=light or set background=dark in your .vimrc.

Comment: It is xterm-256color on the Report terminal type setting. When I open emacs on my local machine with item2 the color looks fine. It's just on the remote server it seems for most themes such as solarize the color is gone.

Answer (score 0):

For Emacs at least, I find that the key is to set `COLORTERM` to `"truecolor"` in the environment, per https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq/Colors-on-a-TTY.html